# Determining circumference of a graph

Tags: graphs

The **circumference** of a graph is the length of any longest cycle in the graph. The  problem  of determining circumference of a graph should be NP-complete. However, for graphs of moderate size, is there also a clever brute-force approach?

I referred to the [link](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/longest-cycle-in-a-directed-or-undirected-graph/7834), where someone mentioned that the **Johnson's algorithm** is the most efficient. However, I'm not sure about the source of this algorithm or if there's an existing implementation based on it. When it comes to finding the longest cycle, I currently feel that the software *Mathematica* might be most effective (although there is no direct command for it). As for open-source programs, the one I've come across is the one below, but its efficiency doesn't seem to be notably high.

- https://github.com/coldwarrior5/Graph-analyser/tree/master/longest-cycle

I once raised this question on the [Mathematica stack](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286881/how-to-calculate-the-circumference-of-a-graph), and they suggested that I should start by looking for algorithms. Are there any references or surveys on the theory or algorithms related to finding the longest cycle?

Comment: Johnson's algorithm is for finding shortest paths, it's not going to be useful in your situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the following problem is very hard:

**Problem:** Long Cycle 
**Input:** A graph $G$ and an integer $k$
**Question:** Does $G$ have a simple cycle of length at least $k$?

The problem is clearly NP-complete as it is a generalization of Hamiltonian Cycle (the problem has a cycle of length at least $n$ if and only if the graph is Hamiltonian).

There is no fast algorithm for this problem, and to the best of my knowledge, the fastest FPT algorithm runs in time $O(4.884^k \cdot n^{O(1)})$ [1].

---

[1] Fedor V. Fomin, Daniel Lokshtanov, Fahad Panolan, Saket Saurabh, Meirav Zehavi,
[Long directed (s,t)-path: FPT algorithm](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ipl.2018.04.018),
Information Processing Letters, 2018

Comment: Indeed. If a search for the longest cycle remains effective for graphs with up to 100 vertices, that would be good for me. I just see an article ( https://doi.org/10.1002/net.3230060206)  that formulated it as an integer programming problem. I have not implemented it yet, so I'm unsure about its effectiveness in my examples (about 50 vertices).

Comment: Do you need the absolute longest cycle, or is it enough to find a $k$-cycle?

Comment: You can easily model the $k$-cycle problem as a SAT instance and use off-the-shelf SAT solvers.  That could work

Comment: Thanks. Currently, I'm only concerned with finding the longest cycle (or determining the longest cycle starting from a specific vertex.）But searching for a k-cycle is equivalent in some sense to finding the longest cycle. Do you have any book recommendations on satisfiability (SAT)? It would be great if there are some examples related to graph theory.

Comment: I don't but you can check out [The International SAT Competition Web Page](http://www.satcompetition.org/) and specifically the [Glucose SAT solver](https://www.labri.fr/perso/lsimon/research/glucose/), which is [open source](https://github.com/audemard/glucose).

Comment: When it comes to encoding your problem as a SAT instance, you simply create "slots" $s_{i, v}$ for each position $i$ in the cycle, and $v$ a vertex in the graph.  Then you need to add the constraints that each vertex is in at most one slot, each slot is filled, and for two neighboring slots, they share an edge.  I think this is textbook material, so you might find this verbatim if you go look for it.